# Connecting Simba ODBC driver for big query issue - SSL Verification

Tags: ms-access, ssl, google-bigquery, odbc, simba

When I tried to connect with bigquery using OAuth Mechanism as "user Authentication" we are facing below error getting Refresh token

```
DSN configuration Error.

(1120) SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate
```

We cannot get catalog and dataset information from the dropdown.

Comment: The error message most likely means exactly what it says.

Comment: @RobertHarvey , can you please elaborate

Comment: Have you checked to see if the server host name specified for the connection matches the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate?

Comment: @Surya Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there can be many reasons to get this kind of error. You can see these solutions:

1. If you are behind a `proxy/VPN/firewall/load balancer` balancer, it could
   affect the connection. I recommend trying to bypass any
   `proxy/VPN/firewall/load balancer`. You can see all the URLs in this
   [document](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/features/endpoints.htm?Highlight=service%20endpoint).
2. You can follow these steps:

- a. Editing the Google BigQuery ODBC connection under the system DSN
  tab.
- b. Checking the box to use 'System trust store' and unticking the box
  for proxy settings.
- c. Authentication using 'user authentication' and the refresh token.

3. Check the version:
   If you are using a `Microsoft Office product`, you need to check that the Simba driver and the Microsoft Office have the same versions 32 bits or 64 bits.
4. Check that you are not using `localhost` as the hostname in the configuration.

Comment: Hi @Raul, It's the issue with trust certificate and we are able to connect. Thank you for the detailed info.

Comment: @Surya I am glad you were able to connect to the BQ database, do you have any other issues with the connection I can help you with?

Comment: As of now i am good with the connection , will definitely bug you in the coming days . Thanks a lot @Raul